# Assign command output to a variable and do if branch on the return value

Tags: bash

I want to do the following thing

```
X=$(some_command)
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  do_something
  echo $x
else
  do_something_else
fi
```

Basically, I want to execute some command, store the output to some variable.  Meanwhile, I want to branch based on whether the command succeeded or not.  The above way works, but looks ugly.  Is it a smarter way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if x=$(some command); then
  do_something
  echo $x
else
  do_something_else
fi
```

The `if` command works by running the command and testing whether it was successful, and executing the `then` or `else` branch depending on it.

Comment: Does this actually switch on the return value of the program?

Comment: Yes, `if` tests the same thing as the assignment of `$?` in the OP's question.

Comment: It works.  I can't accept it right now since SO has a 10min's time limit.

Comment: Wow, it honestly looks like a new programmer error (`if(x=5)` instead of `if(x==5)`).  Interesting, +1

Comment: Yes, I agree that it looks weird. I'm not sure I advocate this, because it could be confusing. The original code makes it very clear what's going on.