# assign a variable with the value from a command + bash

Tags: bash

How do i assign variable with the value from a command?

This is a very basic example of a variable assignment:

```
$ line_count=2

$ echo $line_count
2
```

This is the command(the value 3) I would like to assign to a variable:

```
$ wc -l < file1.csv
3
```

But I have tried this but this does not work:

```
$ line_count2=wc -l file1.csv
-sh: -l: command not found
```

How can this be done?

Comment: found answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15845412/assign-command-output-to-a-variable-and-do-if-branch-on-the-return-value)

Answer (score 0):

one way to do it is:

```
$ line_count2=$(wc -l < file1.csv)

$ echo $line_count2
```